# How to use the same linestyle for different isolines in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I need assistance on how I can use the same linestyle in ternary diagrams where there is no need for using different colors, linestyles and legends.An example is given in the following programme which gave me the result in three colors and three linestyles.I wish to remove the legend,colour in the isolines and use the same linestyle for the three plotted coordinates at 0.9,0.8 and 0.7 isolines.Thanks.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

 \pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\usepgfplotslibrary{ternary}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{ternaryaxis}[
           ternary limits relative=false,
           width=7.5cm,
           height=7.5cm,
           ymax=1.0,
           clip=false,
           disabledatascaling,
           minor tick num=1,
           grid=both,
%          xlabel=A,
 %         ylabel=B,
 %         zlabel=C,
 ]

\addplot3 coordinates {
       (0.9047, 0.0953, 0.0000)
             (0.9019,   0.0883, 0.0098)
             (0.8993,   0.0806, 0.0201)
             (0.8969,   0.0722, 0.0309)
             (0.8950,   0.0630, 0.0420)
             (0.8936,   0.0532, 0.0532)
             (0.8929,   0.0428, 0.0643)
             (0.8930,   0.0321, 0.0749)
             (0.8938,   0.0212, 0.0850)
             (0.8953,   0.0105, 0.0942)
             (0.8975,   0.0000, 0.1025)
        };

\addplot3 coordinates {
        (0.8209,    0.1791, 0.0000)
              (0.8131,  0.1682, 0.0187)
              (0.8054,  0.1557, 0.0389)
              (0.7980,  0.1414, 0.0606)
              (0.7913,  0.1252, 0.0835)
              (0.7859,  0.1071, 0.1071)
              (0.7823,  0.0871, 0.1306)
              (0.7810,  0.0657, 0.1533)
              (0.7822,  0.0436, 0.1742)
              (0.7859,  0.0214, 0.1927)
              (0.7917,  0.0000, 0.2083)
        };

\addplot3 coordinates {
            (0.7439,    0.2561, 0.0000)
     (0.7313,   0.2418, 0.0269)
     (0.7186,   0.2251, 0.0563)
     (0.7060,   0.2058, 0.0882)
     (0.6942,   0.1835, 0.1223)
     (0.6841,   0.1580, 0.1580)
     (0.6767,   0.1293, 0.1940)
     (0.6729,   0.0981, 0.2290)
     (0.6734,   0.0653, 0.2613)
            (0.6777,    0.0322, 0.2901)
            (0.6848,    0.0000, 0.3152)
        };

 \node[fill=white,draw] at (0.5,{sqrt(3)/2}) {$Sn$};

\node[fill=white,draw]  at (0,0) {$Sb$}; 

\node[fill=white,draw]  at (1,0) {$Bi$}; 

\legend{0.9, 0.8,0.7}

\end{ternaryaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you include a simple example?

Comment: Many thanks for your comments.My desire is to remove the color and use the same linestyle for the the plotted isolines in the ternary diagram.For example,in the pgfplots manual page 389 of section 5.10 assuming I want to remove the color for 10degree and 20degree coordinates and use the same linestyle for the two what do I need to do to the programme?I wish I could send the code of the programme i am using but it is too long to be taken by available space here(about 1200 characters).Thanks.

Comment: You can edit your question to include the example, there should be a link at the bottom of the post.

Comment: Thanks T.T,I have edited the question to include the example.

Answer (score 6):

To use the same line style for all contour lines, use `\addplot [black] ...` instead of just `\addplot`. To get rid of the marks, use `no markers`. To get rid of the legend, remove the `\legend{...` line:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usepgfplotslibrary{ternary}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{ternaryaxis}[
           ternary limits relative=false,
           width=7.5cm,
           height=7.5cm,
           ymax=1.0,
           minor tick num=1,
           grid=both,
           no markers,
           xlabel=Sn,
           xlabel style={
            at={(axis cs:1,0,0)},
            anchor=south
           },
           ylabel=Sb,
           ylabel style={
            at={(axis cs:0,1,0)},
            anchor=10
           },
           zlabel=Bi,
           zlabel style={
            at={(axis cs:0,0,1)},
            anchor=north west
           },
 ]

\addplot3 [black, dashed] coordinates {
       (0.9047, 0.0953, 0.0000)
             (0.9019,   0.0883, 0.0098)
             (0.8993,   0.0806, 0.0201)
             (0.8969,   0.0722, 0.0309)
             (0.8950,   0.0630, 0.0420)
             (0.8936,   0.0532, 0.0532)
             (0.8929,   0.0428, 0.0643)
             (0.8930,   0.0321, 0.0749)
             (0.8938,   0.0212, 0.0850)
             (0.8953,   0.0105, 0.0942)
             (0.8975,   0.0000, 0.1025)
        };

\addplot3 [black, dashed] coordinates {
        (0.8209,    0.1791, 0.0000)
              (0.8131,  0.1682, 0.0187)
              (0.8054,  0.1557, 0.0389)
              (0.7980,  0.1414, 0.0606)
              (0.7913,  0.1252, 0.0835)
              (0.7859,  0.1071, 0.1071)
              (0.7823,  0.0871, 0.1306)
              (0.7810,  0.0657, 0.1533)
              (0.7822,  0.0436, 0.1742)
              (0.7859,  0.0214, 0.1927)
              (0.7917,  0.0000, 0.2083)
        };

\addplot3 [black, dashed] coordinates {
            (0.7439,    0.2561, 0.0000)
     (0.7313,   0.2418, 0.0269)
     (0.7186,   0.2251, 0.0563)
     (0.7060,   0.2058, 0.0882)
     (0.6942,   0.1835, 0.1223)
     (0.6841,   0.1580, 0.1580)
     (0.6767,   0.1293, 0.1940)
     (0.6729,   0.0981, 0.2290)
     (0.6734,   0.0653, 0.2613)
            (0.6777,    0.0322, 0.2901)
            (0.6848,    0.0000, 0.3152)
        };
\end{ternaryaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Jake.Your suggestions really worked.However,the axis labels are expected to be at the corners and not by the sides.How do I improve on this?Also,if I desire to use line-dashes and not solid lines for the isolines what do I need to do?Regards.

Comment: @OluseyiAwe: I've edited my answer. Are you sure it's a good idea to label the corners instead of the sides though? That way, viewers might be confused whether a point in the lower right corner represents 0% Bi, or 100% Bi.

Comment: That is the way it is done in this context Jake.I am most grateful.Additional questions: (1.) If I need to draw two or more similar ternary diagrams and put them on one page what do I need to do?Also,(2.) if the ternary diagrams have to be inserted in an article in latex (as in publication) what do I need to do?Thanks.

Comment: @OluseyiAwe: If you want to put two ternary diagrams on the same page, put each in its own `tikzpicture` environment and treat those like you would treat a picture (`\begin{figure}\centering\begin{tikzpicture}\begin{axis}`, for example). For submitting an article including TikZ images to a journal, you can create individual PDFs of the figures using the TikZ `external` library.

Comment: Jake,I have tried this and it worked.However,the diagrams are placed side by side(horizontally).What do I need to do to put them vertically?Is it possible to label the diagrams as Fig.1,Fig.2etc?

Comment: @OluseyiAwe: You should probably open a new question for this